# OneToOne JPA / Hibernate eager loading cause N+1 select

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I created a method to have multilingual text on different objects without creating field for each languages or tables for each objects types.

Now the only problem I've got is N+1 select queries when doing a simple loading.

**Tables schema :**

```
CREATE TABLE `testentities` (
  `keyTestEntity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyMultilingualText` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`keyTestEntity`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `common_multilingualtexts` (
  `keyMultilingualText` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`keyMultilingualText`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `common_multilingualtexts_values` (
  `languageCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `keyMultilingualText` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`languageCode`,`keyMultilingualText`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**MultilingualText.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "common_multilingualtexts")
public class MultilingualText implements Serializable
{
    private Integer m_iKeyMultilingualText;
    private Map<String, String> m_lValues = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void setKeyMultilingualText(Integer p_iKeyMultilingualText)
    {
        m_iKeyMultilingualText = p_iKeyMultilingualText;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "keyMultilingualText")
    public Integer getKeyMultilingualText()
    {
        return m_iKeyMultilingualText;
    }

    public void setValues(Map<String, String> p_lValues)
    {
        m_lValues = p_lValues;
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "common_multilingualtexts_values", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "keyMultilingualText"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "languageCode")
    @Column(name = "value")
    public Map<String, String> getValues()
    {
        return m_lValues;
    }

    public void put(String p_sLanguageCode, String p_sValue)
    {
        m_lValues.put(p_sLanguageCode,p_sValue);
    }

    public String get(String p_sLanguageCode)
    {
        if(m_lValues.containsKey(p_sLanguageCode))
        {
            return m_lValues.get(p_sLanguageCode);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And it is used like this on a object (having a foreign key to the multilingual text) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testentities")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable
{
    private Integer m_iKeyEntity;
    private MultilingualText m_oText;

    public void setKeyEntity(Integer p_iKeyEntity)
    {
        m_iKeyEntity = p_iKeyEntity;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "keyEntity")
    public Integer getKeyEntity()
    {
        return m_iKeyEntity;
    }


    public void setText(MultilingualText p_oText)
    {
        m_oText = p_oText;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "keyText")
    public MultilingualText getText()
    {
        return m_oText;
    }
}
```

Now, when doing a simple HQL query : `from TestEntity`, I get a query selecting `TestEntity`'s and one query for each `MultilingualText` that need to be loaded on each `TestEntity`. I've searched a lot and found absolutely no solutions. I have tested :

- `@Fetch(FetchType.JOIN)`
- `optional = false`
- `@ManyToOne` instead of `@OneToOne`

Now I am out of idea!

**Edit :**

I use Hibernate 4.2.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these annotations:

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
```

Additionally you always could `LEFT JOIN FETCH`, which is the implementation-agnostic solution to your specific problem (ONE-TO-ONE):

```
SELECT e1 From entity1 e1 LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.oneToOneRel e2 WHERE...
```

Comment: Tried these annotations on `getText()`, same result.

Comment: Could you show us also the the ID column in `TestEntity` (both field and getter/setter with their annotations)?

Comment: Here it is, pretty straighforward

Comment: Seems OK, wanted just to check that you annotated ONLY either the getters, or the fields.

Comment: Have you also tried to remove the property `getValues()` from `MultilingualText` to exclude a BUG? Also what version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: Replacing all annotations on `getValues()` and replacing by `@Transient` get the same problem. Give me one second I'll append version in question.

Comment: Could you try the last version 4.3.5-Final ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55364/discussion-between-alexandre-lavoie-and-andrei-i).

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN FETCH` works, but I'll wait to see if there are other possibilities. Since I'll use theses entities everywhere, I hope I will not need to do this everywhere too!